# error in multi batch transactional sql script

Tags: sql-server

```
  BEGIN TRAN
  SET XACT_ABORT ON

  GO

  BEGIN TRY
   IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Offer_GetByStudyId', 'p') IS NULL
  EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE Offer_GetByStudyId as select 1')
  END TRY

 BEGIN CATCH
 THROW;
  END CATCH

 GO
 IF @@error <> 0 and @@trancount > 0 ROLLBACK
 IF @@trancount = 0 BEGIN SET NOCOUNT ON; SET NOEXEC ON; END
 GO

  BEGIN TRY

  ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Offer_GetByStudyId
  @StudyId NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
  AS
 BEGIN
  DECLARE @Conditions NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

IF @StudyId IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @Conditions = @Conditions + ' AND o.StudyId = ' + cast(@StudyId as varchar(10))
END

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT
    o.StudyId as StudyId,
    o.SampleId as SampleId,
    o.Status as Status,
    o.Title as Title,
    o.Topic as Topic,
    o.Description as Description,
    o.TestOffer as TestOffer,
    T.CPI as CPI
    FROM Offers o
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Terms] T ON (o.[Id] = T.[OfferId]) AND T.Active = 1
    WHERE 1 = 1' + @Conditions

    EXEC(@sql)
END
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    THROW;
END CATCH
```

This is my SQL script, I'm trying to have a multi batch script run as a single transaction, so if one statement fails, all of it will be rolled back. But I here keep getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near BEGIN. expecting EXTERNAL

The begin they are talking about is the one after:

```
@StudyId NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
```

Comment: What's the point in altering a procedure inside another procedure?

Comment: You're trying to do procedure installation inside a transaction? I don't see the point of that since the create is just doing a dummy procedure, and if the alter procedure fails, it will leave the old version into the database.

Comment: Also, your procedure is vulnerable for SQL injection. You should use sp_executesql and variables instead of exec and concatenating values into the sql.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove your "GO" statements.  These are not part of the TSQL language, they are just statements to tell SSMS/SQLCMD that the batch above should be executed.  I'm not clear on the behavior of a transaction split across several GO statements.  I would start my removing the "GO"s.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188037.aspx

Comment: Batches and Transactions are completely separate in SQL Server. A single transaction can contain multiple batches. A single batch can contain multiple transactions.

Answer (score 0):

If you take out the statement `ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.Offer_GetByStudyId (Line 22 - 47)` from TRY CATCH it will work. 
i.e delete `TRY CATCH (Line 20 and Line 48 - 51)`

Answer (score 0):

I've realised I've buried the answer in the below, so I'll bring it up to the top to make it clearer: you **cannot** wrap any flow control statements around an attempt to create or alter a procedure

---

A simpler example demonstrates the problem:

```
create procedure ABC
as
go
select * from sys.objects
alter procedure ABC as
```

Which produces the message:

```
Msg 111, Level 15, State 1, Procedure ABC, Line 2
'CREATE/ALTER PROCEDURE' must be the first statement in a query batch.
```

This is explicitly documented for [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187926.aspx) but for some reason isn't for [`ALTER PROCEDURE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189762.aspx).

> The `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement cannot be combined with other Transact-SQL statements in a single batch.

So the upshot is, you cannot wrap any flow control statements around an attempt to create or alter a procedure.

---

The reason is actually pretty simple - `BEGIN` and `END` aren't *required* around the body of the stored procedure - and a stored procedure can actually contain multiple "top-level" `BEGIN`/`END` pairs:

```
create procedure ABC as
begin 
    select * from sys.objects
end
begin 
    select * from sys.columns
end
```

is fine - so the only way that SQL Server knows the extent of a stored procedure, when it's being defined, is "from the `CREATE`/`ALTER` `PROCEDURE` until the end of the batch."

Comment: how can I fix it, while still keeping the logic, which is a multi batch rollable transaction

Comment: @GeorgesL - you can either wrap the entire procedure definition up as a string and deal with all of the quote escaping, so you can `EXEC` it, as you have with the `CREATE`, or you can accept that there's not a great deal of value in the `TRY`/`CATCH` there and remove them. I'd favour the second route normally.